# Ошибка при отправке ответа в Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, spring-mvc, axios

Здравствуйте возникла проблема со Spring MVC, пример заключается в следующем:

#### Controller

```
@RestController
public class ResultsTabController extends AdminRoomController {

    @Autowired
    private ResultUsersService resultUsersService;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/adminRoom/results/getResults", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ResultUser> getAllResultstUsers(){
        logger.trace("Request[/adminRoom/results/getResults] for get all the results users.");
        return resultUsersService.getAllResultsUsers();
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Service

```
@Service
public class ResultUsersServiceImpl implements ResultUsersService {

    @Autowired
    private ResultUserRepository resultUserRepository;

    ...

    public List<ResultUser> getAllResultsUsers() {
        return resultUserRepository.findAll();
    }

    ...

}
```

#### Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "results")
public class ResultUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "time", nullable = true)
    private Timestamp time;

    @Column(name = "result", nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String result;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public ResultUser() {}

    public ResultUser(Timestamp time, String result, User user) {
        this.time = time;
        this.result = result;
        this.user = user;
    }

    // Getter and setters

}
```

#### Request

```
var self = this;
axios.get('/adminRoom/results/getResults').then(function (response) {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        self.$root.$data.results.push({
            name : response.data[i].user.name,
            login : response.data[i].user.login,
            data : response.data[i].data,
            result : response.data[i].result
        });
   }
});
```

И в ответ я принимаю крайне непонятную вещь, получается что ответ зацикливается чтоли... Хотя на сервере принтами выводил информация как надо приходит в контроллер, а вот из контроллера к клиенту приходит следующее:

```
[{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":{"id":6,"login":"vov","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","name":"vovka","resultsUser":[{"id":1,"time":"May 17, 2018 4:38:42 PM","result":"0/7","user":
```

Это не весь ответ... Ошибка которую выдает мне Google Chrome:
    Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
    Error: Network Error
        at e.exports (spread.js:25)
        at XMLHttpRequest.l.onerror (spread.js:25)

Юуду очень благодарен тому, кто подскажет в чем дело, потому уже и не знаю, что с этим делать...

Comment: Покажите как зацикливается

Comment: Вон JSON объект закциливаемый представлен

Answer (score 2):

У вас ResultUser вытягивает User ,а User вытягивает ResultUser циклически. Добавьте аннотации:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
private User user;
```

А в User :

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Теперь возникла проблема: Failde to load response. В PostMan пробовал отправить запрос но выбивает ошибку, хотя в браузер приходит статус 200, с чем это может быть связано?